# Spring Aop,Web Service :- Is is possible to get the name along with the value in an aspect

Tags: spring, web-services, aop, spring-aop

Is it possible to get the name of the parameter dynamically along with the value.Since getArgs() gives me the value only and not the name which in this case is "userid"...... i m using a web service here

```
@Before("allGenericAppServiceImplMethods()")
public void LoggingAdvice(JoinPoint joinPoint){

Object[] arguments = joinPoint.getArgs();
for(int i=0;i<arguments.length;i++){                      
    Object a=arguments[i];
}
System.out.println(a);
}

@Pointcut("execution(public * com.nrollup.service.impl.GenericAppServiceImpl.*(..))")
public void allGenericAppServiceImplMethods()
{}
```

---

```
ServiceClass.java 

    public Response deleteNews(
        @FormParam("userid") String tuserid,   
        @FormParam("id") String id,                     
        @FormParam("sid") String sid);
```

Comment: Do you actually want the name of the `@FormParam("userid")`, which would be `"userid"` or the name of the method parameter, which would be `"tuserid"`"?

Comment: @AdamMichalik Which ever is possible... I am doing this for the first time... so any of "userid" or "tuserid"...i just want the name of the value.... thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You asked a similar question here on StackOverflow when you were already one step further and I have posted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38540934/1082681) solving your problem with JDK dynamic proxies vs. CGLIB. I think my answer also answers this question, so maybe you want to close them both it by accepting the answer(s) and upvoting.