# Spring AOP :- Getting parameterNames as null in the joinPoint

Tags: java, web-services, aop, spring-aop

LoggingAspect.java

```
@Around("allGenericAppServiceImplMethods()")
public Object LoggingAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint)throws Throwable{

MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature)joinPoint.getSignature();
String[] parameterNames = signature.getParameterNames();

Object[] arguments = joinPoint.getArgs();
```

I am getting parameterNames as null.How do I get the parameterNames?

Answer (score 3):

I just checked in plain AspectJ and I never get parameter names as `null` with AspectJ 1.8.6. Maybe you use an older version and need to upgrade to the current version (1.8.9). The parameter names are displayed correctly if the class files in question were compiled with the corresponding debug info. But even if the debug info was stripped or you are accessing parameter names for JDK methods, at least AspectJ will spit out names like `arg0`, `arg1` etc.

**Update:** The problem does not exist in pure AspectJ or in AspectJ LTW used in Spring applications, only in proxy-based Spring AOP with JDK dynamic proxies. I could reproduce the problem with a little sample project I cloned from somewhere on GitHub.

The solution if you are programming against interfaces is to enforce CGLIB usage for proxies even though the default here is JDK proxies.

So if your configuration looks like this ...

```xml
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
```

... just change it to:

```xml
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
<aop:config proxy-target-class="true">
    <!-- other beans defined here... -->
</aop:config>
```

Then try again and enjoy. :-)

Comment: Hello @kriegaex ! I am currently using AspectJ 1.6.11. I will  upgrade to the latest version and check....

Comment: I just upgraded my aspectj's maven dependency to 1.8.9....still I am getting parameterNames as null...Is this problem something related to jdk or cglib proxy?...

Comment: hey @kriegaex i tried changing the configuration file as you suggested, but still i am getting parameterNames as null, i read some other post which said that the bytecode does not include the parameter names, it requires the debug information for the parameter names to be included, is there some other workaround for this problem ?

Comment: If you strip the debug info from the code, how/why do you expect to see debug info such as parameter names?